# How to create kubernetes secret using json file content and stringData field

Tags: json, kubernetes, yaml

I am trying to create a secret using JSON file content and stringData like below but giving some error which I am not able to identify after multiple tries.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: image-secret
  type: Opaque
stringData:
   creds: _json_key:{"type": "service_account","project_id": "xyz","private_key_id": "9b0eb25b41ae9161123dbfh56mgj","private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nmch0iiFz1DAdM8vQTXiETI+3gvSnknXQ0M5WmkA1dkiJgyhe3r8tpeb42jo4FCd\nbHLf9eeIql8TKEm9BAk+qnQZq8FykWEnQLuU7APrFNZ0qtYP8t1Y7HSGpdVmmCyK\nykJAGznKaiEf9SJiNy8HqJy1kOhajn1fL3CdcShWcY793qRLyeFyrIZ\n6lfnjSE9IW5iEOBmxEpXf5Q=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n","client_email": "argocd-image-updater@xyz.iam.","client_id": "113522222222222222222222222","auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com,"token_uri": "https://oauth.googleap,"auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth/v1/certs","client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/v1"}
```

username as **_json_key** and password is **"json file content"**

The error which I am getting is as below:-

```
error: error parsing argocd-image-updater-secret.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 7: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting bitten by a yaml-ism, as `yaml2json` or `yamllint` would inform you

```
Error: Cannot parse as YAML (mapping values are not allowed here
  in "<byte string>", line 5, column 28:
       creds: _json_key:{"type": "service_account","project_id" ... 
                               ^)
```

what you'll want is to fold that scalar so the `:`  is clearly character data and not parsed as a yaml key

```yaml
metadata:
  name: image-secret
  type: Opaque
stringData:
   creds: >-
     _json_key:{"type": "service_account","project_id": "xyz","private_key_id": "9b0eb25b41ae9161123dbfh56mgj","private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nmch0iiFz1DAdM8vQTXiETI+3gvSnknXQ0M5WmkA1dkiJgyhe3r8tpeb42jo4FCd\nbHLf9eeIql8TKEm9BAk+qnQZq8FykWEnQLuU7APrFNZ0qtYP8t1Y7HSGpdVmmCyK\nykJAGznKaiEf9SJiNy8HqJy1kOhajn1fL3CdcShWcY793qRLyeFyrIZ\n6lfnjSE9IW5iEOBmxEpXf5Q=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n","client_email": "argocd-image-updater@xyz.iam.","client_id": "113522222222222222222222222","auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com,"token_uri": "https://oauth.googleap,"auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth/v1/certs","client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/v1"}
```